# Codigniter is not working after uploading to Linux server

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, deployment

Created an application using Codeginiter and is working fine with my local environment which is in XAMPP.
After uploading application folders and files to linux server application is not working at all. 
Deployed complete files under "/var/www/html/" and when access from browser it gives me CI error as "404 Page Not Found".

After uploading, I have updated .htaccess file.

Comment: In Linux created filenames are capital sensitive, in Windows they are not. Maybe search in that direction?

Comment: all my controller and model are as per the rules given by CI. Even i tried using index.php, getting same result.

Comment: Can you please share the .htaccess code you uploaded?

Comment: Add an index.php to a different folder on the server and see if you can access it by its URL

Comment: Most certainly a `.htaccess` issue. Please post it, along with your application's `$config['base_url']` var

Answer (score -1):

I think this is about Linux file permission. You might want to check its file permission.

try to change the permission to read, write and executed by you ONLY 
example:

```
sudo chmod 700 var/www/html
```

Comment: Please comment why you downvote, so that i can improve or delete this answer.

Comment: A CI page not found is likely not caused by permissions. His middleware will warn him if that's  the  case.